# how to remove the focus of checkbox in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to have a `ListView` where each row has some text and a `checkbox`. When I click on list view it will check or uncheck the check this is done but I want to disable the focus of `checkbox` i.e. the priority is given to list items not the `checkbox` here the code of `checkbox` and `listview`.

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_field_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

<ListView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@id/listView"
        android:dividerHeight="0.25dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:divider="@color/colorDarkgrey"
        android:background="@color/colorwhite"> </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your item layout xml , you can add this attr in root view

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

try this. and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability) is the api for this attr.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <CheckBox
    ...
    ></CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your item layout should like this.

Comment: can you provide me any sample for this

Comment: pls provide some example